# How can I change where Windows 7 puts its temporary files?

Tags: windows-7

Can I somehow change where temporary files are stored in Windows 7?

Comment: What type of temp files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer no. Due to the way UAC works this is tightly controlled by the operating system. I would suggest just running Disk Cleanup periodically to ensure that it doesn't get filled to quickly.

Comment: Ok. Not a big deal, was just curious :) Thanks!

Comment: What about System Properties->Environment Variables, and the TEMP,TMP folders?

Comment: @ChrisS Those are not used by Windows. Only by the Command Prompt

Comment: If I correctly recall, there was a way to change the temporary folder used in previous versions of Windows; I think it was necessary to change the value in the configuration registry. I don't know if that is changed in Windows 7; this is the reason I am not posting this note as an answer.